# Pearson correlation output in SPSS

Tags: correlation, spss, pearson-r

In my research, I am trying to show the relationship between an IV and a DV.

As I compute the Pearson correlation through SPSS, it outputs a correlation matrix. This is not what I want. I need an $r$ and a $p$ value only.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Tan! I encourage you to read the FAQ, focusing in particular on how to ask effective questions here. Please update your post accordingly so that we can then try to help you. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

For this the output format in SPSS it is always a matrix. You can take it in excel and modify it...or if you want automation use R ... you can take as output more fragmented.